# Can't I use the req.user inside promises in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, node-schedule

I am trying to do the stripe payment using nodejs and I am getting the following errors. One in console and one in web app UI in the browser. What are the reasons?
Also I am trying to use req.user property details which are saved in mongoDB.
I am getting the console error as : `(node:6344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscriptionPlan' of undefined`
and on browser =>

```
 Error: You cannot use a Stripe token more than once: tok_1IJggu*******************.
```

Below is my code:

```
  router.post('/processPayment/:priceID', (req, res) => {

     console.log("plan Token = "+ req.body.stripeToken);
     console.log("plan Email = "+ req.body.stripeEmail);
     var dateFormated, dateFormated2;

     return stripe2.customers.create({
       source: req.body.stripeToken,
       email: req.body.stripeEmail
     }).then(customer => {
       stripe2.subscriptions.create({
         customer: customer.id,
         items: [
           {
             plan: req.params.priceID
           }
         ]
       }).then(subscription => {
         console.log("subscription.status = "+ subscription.status);
         dateFormated = new Date();
         dateFormated2 = new Date();
         console.log(dateFormated2.getMinutes() +' '+dateFormated2.getHours()+' '+dateFormated2.getDate() + ' * *');

         var j = schedule.scheduleJob(dateFormated2.getMinutes() +' '+dateFormated2.getHours()+' '+dateFormated2.getDate() + ' * *',function(){
           var snm = new Date();

           return stripe2.subscriptions.retrieve(req.user.subsID)
           .then(subsData => {
             console.log("Status = "+ subsData.status);
            if(subsData.status == 'active')
            {
           User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.user.id},
             {$set: {"subscriptionDuplicateDate":req.user.subscriptionNextMonth }},
           function (error, data) {
                 if (error) {
                     console.log(error);
                     return res.render("error",{error:error});
                 }
                 else if(req.user.subscriptionPlan == '$299' || req.user.subscriptionPlan == '$499' || req.user.subscriptionPlan == '$999')
                 {
                   snm = snm.setMonth(snm.getMonth() + 1);
                   console.log("snm = "+ snm);
                   User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.user.id},
                     {$set: {"subscriptionNextMonth" : new Date(snm.toLocaleString())}},
                   function (error, data) {
                         if (error) {
                             console.log(error);
                             return res.render("error",{error:error});
                         }
                       })
                   console.log('Your scheduled job every month');
                 }
                 else if(req.user.subscriptionPlan == '$2990' || req.user.subscriptionPlan == '$4990' || req.user.subscriptionPlan == '$9990')
                 {
                   snm = snm.setFullYear(snm.getFullYear() + 1);
                   console.log("snm = "+ snm);
                   User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.user.id},
                     {$set: {"subscriptionNextMonth" :  new Date(snm.toLocaleString())}},
                   function (error, data) {
                         if (error) {
                             console.log(error);
                             return res.render("error",{error:error});
                         }
                       })
                   console.log('Your scheduled job every year');
                 }
               })
             }
             else {
               User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.user.id},
                 {$set: {"subscriptionTotalCount" : 0}},
               function (error, data) {
                     if (error) {
                         console.log(error);
                         return res.render("error",{error:error});
                     }
                   })
             }
             }).catch(err => {
               res.render('error', {message: err});
             });
         });

          if(req.user.subscriptionPlan == '$299' || req.user.subscriptionPlan == '$499' || req.user.subscriptionPlan == '$999')
         {
           User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.user.id},
             {$set: {"subscriptionDate":dateFormated,
                     "subscriptionDuplicateDate":dateFormated,
                     "subscriptionNextMonth":new Date(dateFormated.setMonth(dateFormated.getMonth() + 1))}},
           function (error, data) {
             if(data)
             console.log("subscription date set");
           })
         }
         else if(req.user.subscriptionPlan == '$2990' || req.user.subscriptionPlan == '$4990' || req.user.subscriptionPlan == '$9990')
         {
           User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.user.id},
             {$set: {"subscriptionDate":dateFormated,
                     "subscriptionDuplicateDate":dateFormated,
                     "subscriptionNextMonth":new Date(dateFormated.setFullYear(dateFormated.getFullYear() + 1))}},
           function (error, data) {
             if(data)
             console.log("subscription date set");
           })
         }
         // console.log("subscription.items = "+ JSON.stringify(subscription.items));
         console.dir(subscription);

         res.redirect('/thankyou/0d4a3bc9cd71c4500584f01e7ce74cc6f2a4967ca266f3b7578ff29bd640dbbc/'+customer.id+'/'+subscription.id);
       })
     }).catch(err => {
       res.render('error', {message: err});
     });
   });
```

Comment: Why don’t use async await??

Comment: Does async/await will solve the problem?

Comment: Do not think that your code is too complicated and illegible?

Comment: I think its good.

Comment: `You cannot use a Stripe token more than once` means you are attempting to turn the same Stripe Token into a Source more than once. You're likely calling `customers.create` twice with the same Token, and the second attempt is throwing this error.

Comment: You can see the code above. Its been called only once.

Comment: `You cannot use a Stripe token more than once`, It means the same stripe token is passed more than once. Please check your client side whether the request is firing twice when the previous request  get failed with an some error code. Also do console.log(req.user) to verify if it exists.